# Getting two different hash key, While debugging the android program

Tags: android

I am using this code to get keyhash.

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
```

when I debug this code then, Select "Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT)" and press Shift + ctrl + I, It return keyhash.
again press Shift + ctrl + I, It return different keyhash.

```
Log.d("KeyHash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Please tell me, What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in your method replace line -

```
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
```

on the place of -

```
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
```

it will helps you.

Comment: I have used both "SHA" and "SHA1", both give same result

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [MessageDigest.digest()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html):

> Computes and returns the final hash value for this MessageDigest. **After the digest is computed the receiver is reset**.

It means that after you call `digest()`, the `MessageDigest` object is reset, so you have to call `md.update(signature.toByteArray());` again before calling `digest()` to get the same hash.